# Как загрузить видеофайл в админку django ЧЕРЕЗ КОНСОЛЬ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Есть модели Post и Result. Я хочу через консоль добавить файл (видео) в базу данных админки django.

С текстом делается так:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from posts.models import Post, Result
>>> a = Post.objects.get(id = 3)
a.result_set.create(text = 'text')
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='filesInput/')
    csv = models.FileField(upload_to='filesInput/')
    csvTimeL = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '00:00:02.02')
    csvTimeR = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '00:00:02.4')
    urlTimeL = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 3)
    urlTimeR = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 8)
    siteUrl = models.CharField(max_length = 300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.siteUrl

class Result(models.Model):
    inputData = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    resVideo = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resVideo.url
```

Нужно вместо 'text' вставить файл на локалке.

Comment: Как выглядит поле? Это `FileField`?

Comment: да. Изменил вопрос).

Comment: Посути надо объяснить django что такое файл. Конечный результат: чтобы я програмно смог добавить в results видео файл. P.S. Умоляю, помогите)

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо обернуть файл в специальный класс. Например, в [`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class).

***Пример:***

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from .models import Post, Result


video_name = 'video.webm'
with open(video_name, 'rb') as f:
    video_content = f.read()

post = Post()
post.video.save(video_name, ContentFile(video_content))
post.save()

resVideo_name = 'resVideo.webm'
with open(resVideo_name, 'rb') as f:
    resVideo_content = f.read()

result = Result()
result.inputData = post
result.resVideo.save(resVideo_name, ContentFile(resVideo_content))
result.save()
```

Comment: @MikeDoroshenko Добавьте... Принцип тот же. Вам нужно любой файл обернуть в [`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class). Создайте сначала экземпляр `Post`, потом `Result`. Я не понимаю, в чём у Вас проблема.

Comment: Попробовал:
`
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from posts.models import Post, Result

video_name = 'media//FINALLY0.mp4'
with open(video_name, 'rb') as f:
    video_content = f.read()

a.result_set.create(resVideo = ContentFile(video_content))
`
Получил: 
`
ValueError: The 'resVideo' attribute has no file associated with it.
`

Comment: @MikeDoroshenko Потому что Вы не сохраняете поле `resVideo`. Я в примере специально не использую метод `create`. Вам нужно сначало сохранить поле `resVideo`, и только потом сам экземпляр (с помощью `save`).

Comment: @MikeDoroshenko Это связано с технической реализацией поля `FileField`. Оно хранит не сам файл, а путь к нему (и некоторые мета-данные). Поэтому сначала нужно сохранить сам файл, чтобы получить путь к нему и иметь возможность сохранить экземпляр модели.

Comment: Если Вас не затруднит, можете пожалуйста написать решение для Result.resVideo, потому что я не понимаю как перенести решение для Post.video на Result.resVideo. Так как для Post.video нужно 1 параметр, а для Result.resVideo нужна привязка к посту и видео файл. И огромное вам спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: @MikeDoroshenko Обновил пример.

Comment: Вы - Бог. Спасибо, помогли разобраться.